# MongoDB FindAsync never returns on await

Tags: c#, wpf, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I have looked at all similar threads that deal with **FindAsync** not returning on **await** and none of them helped me solve my problem so I am asking here again.

I am in a WPF application (.Net Framework 4.7.2) and am trying to use MongoDB's C# Driver (latest version 2.9) to find a single item in a collection (there are only 2 items in the collection) using the `FindAsync(filter)` command.

Using the synchronous `Find(filter).SingleOrDefault()` function works just fine (I have a simple FilterDefinition on a name field), also calling other (create) async functions of the driver (like InsertOneAsync) works just fine.

I have also hooked into the client calls by subscribing via `MongoClientSettings.ClusterConfiguration` and `SingleEventSubscribers<CommandSucceededEvent>` (and other commands). The console output clearly tells me that the FindAsync operation is successful. It finds the correct single collection item.

This is my async function (in my generic class):

```
        public async Task<T> GetAsync(FilterDefinition<T> filter)
        {
            var cursor = await Collection.FindAsync(filter);
            return await cursor.SingleOrDefaultAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
```

This is how I call it (from within my ViewModel's constructor):

```
        item = CollectionClass.GetAsync(nameFilter).Result;
```

I debugged my application and it never returns from the FindAsync call and I have no clue why.

Comment: A constructor should not be reaching out to a database or doing any sort of dangerous operation. Hint: any time you use `.Result` in asynchronous code, you're probably doing it wrong. It's likely to cause deadlocks.

Comment: I'm am pretty sure that the .Result will block the current context, not allowing the call to return, which will result in a async deadlock since you are in a WPF application.

Comment: Yep, guys here are right. You are doing sync-over-async that causes dead-lock (just google this term for more information). Use `await` instead of `.Result`. If it is not possible for some reason use `ConfigureAwait(false)`.

Comment: @Artur You can't use `await` in a constructor. Ultimately this code just doesn't belong there.

Comment: You can spawn a new task to perform that Get call so you can await that if it must be initiated from the constructor

Comment: Thanks, the same happens if not called from within my constructor but any other later point in time, so I don't think the constructor itself is the problem here (but how I call this stuff). But I do get that the context is blocked not allowing the call to return (no matter where I call this)! Cheers for that, didn't even think about context here (though I should have as async is clearly involving context snapshots etc.) Spawning a task and awaiting that is working fine, cheers!